# Hide navigation on particular route in React Router V4?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

As shown in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44214654/react-router-4-hide-navigation-when-on-route#44236490), it's possible to render components only if the path matches a given [path-to-regex](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp) expression:

```
<Route path="/(.+)" render={(() => 
    <Navigation loggedInUser={loggedInUser} />
)}/>
```

The above example from the noted answer will render the Navigation component only when there is at least one character in the path after the slash.

**My question is how would you format a valid *path-to-regex* expression that matches all paths except for "/path-without-nav" or an array of paths?**

Comment: Can you tell me why you are doing like this?

Comment: I have a view in my web app that needs to take up the full window. I'll allow users to exit the view via a button somewhere and return to the regular views in the app that have the primary nav.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting concept that I never had to materialize but this might work.

First match all paths to `NavComponent`

Then you can create `NavComponent` as following

```
export default NavComponent extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    state={
        path:this.props.match.path;
    }

    render(){
        {this.state.path.search('your path') ?
            <div>Don't Render</div>
        :     <Navigation loggedInUser={loggedInUser} />}
    }
}
```

Basically you render based on the state

Comment: Makes sense and I'm about to try it out, but I think it could be done as a stateless functional component couldn't it? We're just using a function from props and don't really need to store it in the state right?

Comment: Tried this out wrapping using a <Route /> component to display the <NavComponent /> with path="/", but the path being passed into NavComponent is always "/", so it never matches my "path-without-nav"... I could probably accomplish what I'm looking for if I passed data into the component utilizing Redux, but that doesn't really seem like something you should use Redux for, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Yeah I just ended up implementing it using Redux and a state variable for if they're on the route w/o nav, and rendering it conditionally based off that. But if anyone has a better way that doesn't use Redux please answer/comment :)